# setting a property value after getting data from an api and passing that data to a child component in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, api

In a parent component , I'm getting a data from an API , let say it's an Object with some properties in it.
In the Received Object , "structure" is the property i want to send to a child component , and with that property i add Class to using Renderer2 by checking the value of the "structure".

when i try to add a class to a div element , it says that the div is undefined

Parent Component :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.scss']
})

dashboardModel;

loadReport(){
this.ApiService('The-Api-Url',300).subscribe((result)=>{ 
this.dashboardModel = result.dashboardModel;

})
}
///Number 300 is just to show you , it's not important !
```

Parent Html :

```
<dashboard-view 
[dashboardModel]="dashboardModel"
></dashboard-view>
```

Child Component :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'dashboard-view',
  template: `
<div
  #widgetContainer
  class="container"
  id="widget-view">
</div>
`,
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard-view.component.scss']
})
export class DashboardViewComponent implements OnInit {
constructor(private renderer : Renderer2){}
@Input() dashboardModel
@ViewChild ('widgetContainer') widgetContainer :ElementRef
creatStructure(){
this.renderer.addClass(this.widgetContainer.nativeElement , 'container-edit-mode')
}

ngOninit(){
this.creatStructure()
}
}
```

I Tried Calling the `creatStructure()` Method in OnInit and AfterViewInit and Even in AfterContentInit But it always says that widgetContainer  is Undefined.

stackBlitz Sample Code : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bdpbwx?file=src/app/child/child.component.ts

Comment: Use ngAfterViewInit instead of ngOnInit

Comment: @MikeOne I tried but the api calling is happening after setting dashboardModel Value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several choices I could suggest without that working StackBlitz.

1. Don't use the renderer to set the class.
   Set it in the template with a getter; then you're not worrying about view child objects and order of initialisations.

Template:

```
<div
  #widgetContainer
  class="container"
  [class.container-edit-mode]="isEditMode"
  id="widget-view">
</div>
```

Component:

```
public get isEditMode(): boolean {
  return this.dashboardModel
    && this.dashboardModel.structure
    && this.dashboardModel.structure === '12';
}
```

This guards against the dashboard model not having been set yet (which is your current issue, as the API call happens after initialisation).

2. Only put the component on screen once you have data.
   Hide your component behind an `*ngIf` so that it only gets constructed once you have the data, then you are guaranteed to have `this.dashboardModel` filled at `ngOnInit` time.

Parent template:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="dashboardModel">
  <dashboard-view 
    [dashboardModel]="dashboardModel">
  </dashboard-view>
</ng-container>
```

Note: you still need to sort out your view child initialisation ordering if you stick to direct renderer usage for setting the class...

3. Fix your order of initialisations.
   As already mentioned, if you're going to do things to your view using the renderer, do it in/after the `ngAfterViewInit` stage of the lifecycle. Before then, your template doesn't exist so all your view child objects will remain undefined.

You can switch your input to a `set` so that you can do relevant changes when you do get that API data in and leave your component otherwise uninitialised until then.

Component:

```
@Input() public set dashboardModel(value: DashboardModel) {
  this._dashboardModel = value;
  this.initModel();
}

private initModel(): void {
  if (!this.widgetContainer) console.error(`Hopefully this shouldn't happen`);

  if (this._dashboardModel.structure === '12')
    this.renderer.addClass(this.widgetContainer.nativeElement , 'container-edit-mode');
}
```